# Is there a way of changing the text input on a group of buttons?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am relatively new to swift and Xcode and I am working on a quiz app that will have three answers to each question (one correct, two incorrect). So far I have managed to make the answers link to three buttons where when the correct one is pressed it registers as being the correct answer in my code. However, for each question button one is always the correct answer, button two is always incorrect answer one and button three is always incorrect answer two so is there a way of changing this so it is randomised for each question? Thank you

As I am relatively new to swift I am not aware of how I can randomise the button titles so haven't tried anything yet

**// the code that updates the button titles**

```
questionLabel.text = allQuestions.questions[questionNumber].question
buttonOne.setTitle(allQuestions.questions[questionNumber].answer, for: .normal)
buttonTwo.setTitle(allQuestions.questions[questionNumber].falseAnswerOne, for: .normal)
buttonThree.setTitle(allQuestions.questions[questionNumber].falseAnswerTwo, for: .normal)
```

**// the code that holds the information for each question and answer**

```
class QuestionBank {

var questions = [Question]()

init() {
    questions.append(Question(text: "Question", correctAnswer: "X", wrongAnswerOne: "Y", wrongAnswerTwo: "Z"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your `Question` model to something like this:

```
struct Question {
    let text: String
    var answers: [Answer]
}

enum Answer {
    case correct(String)
    case wring(String)
}

let question = Question(text: "Question", answers: [.correct("X"), .wrong("Y"), .wrong("Z")]
```

To be able to handle correct and wrong answer you need to tell button what type of answer it's connected to. So you need to save not only answer text in button (in title) but also the answer type.

To achieve this you can create your custom `UIButton` subclass with variable `answer: Answer`.

```
class AnswerButton: UIButton {
    var answer: Answer! {
        didSet {
            configureTitle()
        }
    }

    private func configureTitle() {
        switch answer {
            case .correct(let title):
                setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            case .wrong(let title):
                setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

So before assigning answers to buttons you need to shuffle answers and assign them by index.

```
var question = allQuestions.questions[questionNumber]
question.answers.shuffle()
questionLabel.text = question.text
buttonOne.answer = question.answers[0]
buttonTwo.answer = question.answers[1]
buttonThree.answer = question.answers[2]
```

I think you have buttons in Storyboard, so your button `IBAction` will be:

```
@IBAction private func guess(_ sender: AnswerButton) {
    switch sender.answer {
        case .correct:
            // Handle correct answer
        case .wrong:
            // Handle wrong answer
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I've managed to add the first two parts but the second two bring up numerous errors, most of which I don't understand. ill have another look at it and see if I can work out why it is not accepting the new code

Comment: after the buttonOne.answer = question.answers[0] (and the same for two and three) it says 'value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'answer''. to check I am doing it right, I have created a file for the first part (the Struct Question...) and a file for the Class AnswerButton, but where should I include the var question part? thank you

Comment: (ive realised why it was saying over 20 errors is because I have multiple view controller files with the same code for different categories for my app so each view controller file was bringing up the same errors, and there are other ones that I have managed to resolve)

Comment: If you use Storyboard you need to change class of button in it to be able to use your custom UIButton subclass. Click on your button, open Identity inspector (third icon on right panel) and fill Class field in Custom Class section with AnswerButton. Do it with every AnswerButton in all your storyboards.

Comment: ive done that but it doesn't seem to have made any difference, I think the issue is that the variable 'answer' isn't accepted as a property of the buttons. was there anything I needed to change in the AnswerButton class or should it have just worked as you had written it?